# Making ANTLRWorks handle whitespaces automatically

Tags: antlr, grammar, antlrworks

I have an ANTLR grammar like this:

```
grammar HelloGrammar1;

ID  :   ('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z'|'_') ('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z'|'0'..'9'|'_')* ;
STATEMENT : 'hello' ID ';' ;
WS  :   (' '|'\t'|'\r'|'\n')* ;
```

I want it to parse the following text: `hello qwerty ;`. It doesn work this way. If I change my string to `helloqwerty;`, everything is fine. I can also change grammar to:

```
grammar HelloGrammar2;

ID  :   ('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z'|'_') ('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z'|'0'..'9'|'_')* ;
STATEMENT : 'hello' WS ID WS ';' ;
WS  :   (' '|'\t'|'\r'|'\n')* ;
```

And in this case, `hello qwerty ;` works fine. Is it possible to make ANTLR skip whitespaces automatically? (i.e. - I want to make HelloGrammar1 work with `hello qwerty ;`)

**Update**

If it makes sense: I'm testing it in ANTLRWorks.

**Update 2**

Also tried this way:

```
grammar HelloGrammar;

ID  :   ('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z'|'_') ('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z'|'0'..'9'|'_')* ;
STATEMENT : 'hello' ID ';' ;
WS  :   (' '|'\t'|'\r'|'\n') { $channel = HIDDEN; } ;
```

Still doesn't work.

**Update 3**

I'm using "Interpreter" tab with "STATEMENT" rule selected.

Comment: what do want to be allowable input?

Comment: Note that no lexer rule should produce a token that can (potentially) match zero characters (empty string). The lexer would produce an infinite amount of them. So `(' '|'\t'|'\r'|'\n')*` should be either `(' '|'\t'|'\r'|'\n')` or `(' '|'\t'|'\r'|'\n')+`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the issue may be that you should change **STATEMENT** (currently a lexer rule) to **statement** (a parser rule)

```
grammar HelloGrammar;

statement : 'hello' ID ';' ;
ID  :   ('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z'|'_') ('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z'|'0'..'9'|'_')* ;
WS  :   (' '|'\t'|'\r'|'\n') { $channel = HIDDEN; } ;
```

In ANTLRWorks this accepts:

```
hello qwerty;
hello   qwerty;
hello loki2302;
hello   qwerty  ;
```

but does not accept:

```
helloqwerty;
helloqwerty ;
hello;
hello qwerty
```